# Hourly Cron job

Tags: cron

I want to run cron job from the time the cron job created. If I created a cron job at 6:54 p.m. It should run at 7:54 p.m. but the job is running at 7:00 p.m. and then 8, 9 and so one.

Please help
Vipin Bansal

Comment: Can you post the details of your cron job please

Comment: If you want a job that runs at 54 minutes past each hour, you can use the following format: `code`
54 * * * * [your command]
`code` - hope this helps!

Comment: I want a job that runs every hour from the time it was  created. If it was created at 6:45 then it should start running at 7:45, 8:45 and so on but it is running at 7:00, 8:00 and so on and I dont want like the case it is following actually

Comment: Hi - can you post the wording of you crontab command here please?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit cron jobs in linux via the command:

> crontab -e

So in practice what you can do is for example every time a cron job is triggered (for example your first one is at 6:54) add a new line to that crontab file. Below is how I would do it:

In pseudo code:

1. Use the php [exec](https://www.php.net/function.exec) in conjunction with security function [escapeshellcmd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) function, since  I suppose you are using user input as well?
2. Each time there is a need to write to the crontab have a function concatenate the needed time, the php command, and the file location of what you are trying to automate.
3. When setting time you can use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions to create the minutes, hours so you can have more control over your cronjob as you specified as well.

Good luck. Any questions just ask.